# Php MySQL updating columns id only if ip is new

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

Everytime I click on the video link to test my script
instead of adding +1 to the same video name aka (id).
it just keep adding a columns.
How can i stop MySQL from adding more colums and just update the views +1.

```
//Get video id
$id = $_GET['id'];

//Get video title
$videoName = $_GET['idtitle'];

//Connect to DB
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=videodb', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//Reset the ips on database after 7 days? correct me if i'm wrong here 
const HIT_OLD_AFTER_SECONDS = 604800; // Value 1 week.

//Check if connection fail or pass
//if(!$pdo){echo "Fail!";} else {echo "Pass!";}  

//Insert the $id, $videoName, and views 1
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO `videodb`.`videos` (`name`, `title`, `views`) VALUES ('$id', '$videoName', 1)");

//This is where i'm stuck 
//Select name from the database videos table
//If the name inside video table &&(AND) $videoName are equal(TRUE)
//Update views to views +1

if($pdo->query("SELECT `name` FROM `videodb`.`videos`") && $videoName == true ){
    $pdo->query("UPDATE `videos` SET `views` = `views`+1");    
}
```

Comment: **Why are you surprised!** You tell it to INSERT a new row every time through this piece of code.!

Comment: You have already posted this question. I think you have to stop and take a look to basics of [SQL queries](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). **You have to use UPDATE statement AND id of video** (see my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026990/php-mysql-how-to-updated-insert-into-a-database-row): you have to change only a bit of code and have your answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before anything else

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO `videodb`.`videos` (`name`, `title`, `views`) VALUES ('$id', '$videoName', 1)");
```

Is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Moving forward,

```
"UPDATE `videos` SET `views` = `views` + 1 WHERE `id` = '$id'"
```

If you run that SQL syntax on page load it will update your views column +1.

However, for the duplicate IP you'd want to set the 'ip' column to a key and

```
"INSERT INTO `videos` (params) VALUES (params) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `views` = views+1"
```

Comment: Your answer work, But now MySQL is not recognizing the $videoName, views count does go up +1 everytime i refresh, but the video name don't change in my database.

Comment: There is no select statement in what I gave you. If you need to also update the video name just add a comma on the update statement.